# iframe change for sidenav multiple dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have `index.html`, in my `index.html` I have two dropdown-container and iframe.

But it's work in dropdown number one with iframe while dropdown number 2 is doesn't work, anyone can fix this?

I'm confuse on this script for iframe change:

```
function iframeChange() {
var buttons = document.querySelector(".dropdown-container");
var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');

buttons.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  mySelect.src = e.target.dataset.src;
  mySelect.id = e.target.dataset.id;
  mySelect.width = e.target.dataset.width;
  mySelect.height = e.target.dataset.height;
  mySelect.title = e.target.dataset.title;
  iframe.src = e.target.dataset.src;
  iframe.width = e.target.dataset.width;
  iframe.height = e.target.dataset.height;
  iframe.title = e.target.dataset.title;
});
  }

  window.onload = iframeChange;
```

my script running in local pc

```
<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
<button id="mySelect" class="dropdown-btn">BCA - SALES 
  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div id="mySelect" class="dropdown-container">
  <li><a id="mySelect" data-src="https://192.168.90.240/single/?appid=1ab7d1b9-5a9f-4337-9215-7e1e036625d1&sheet=83e3821d-2afc-45bd-be16-7d95a1065a8d&opt=currsel" data-width="100%" data-height="550px">DASHBOARD I</a></li>
  <li><a id="mySelect" data-src="https://192.168.90.240/single/?appid=1ab7d1b9-5a9f-4337-9215-7e1e036625d1&sheet=828499e7-da76-4f1c-aa43-b4accbfbd203&opt=currsel" data-width="100%" data-height="550px">DASHBOARD II</a></li>
  <li><a id="mySelect" data-src="https://192.168.90.240/single/?appid=1ab7d1b9-5a9f-4337-9215-7e1e036625d1&sheet=89c0893e-d526-4af3-aaf8-68a1d54cb96d&opt=currsel" data-width="100%" data-height="550px">DASHBOARD III</a></li>
  <li><a id="mySelect" data-src="https://192.168.90.240/single/?appid=1ab7d1b9-5a9f-4337-9215-7e1e036625d1&sheet=7b3fe051-8219-469f-994b-7ea249ee2b73&opt=currsel" data-width="100%" data-height="550px">DASHBOARD IV</a></li>
</div>
<button id="mySelect" class="dropdown-btn">BCA - MARKETING 
  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</button>
<div id="mySelect" class="dropdown-container">
  <li><a id="mySelect" data-src="https://192.168.90.240/single/?appid=1ab7d1b9-5a9f-4337-9215-7e1e036625d1&sheet=83e3821d-2afc-45bd-be16-7d95a1065a8d&opt=currsel" data-width="100%" data-height="550px">DASHBOARD I</a></li>
  <li><a id="mySelect" data-src="https://192.168.90.240/single/?appid=1ab7d1b9-5a9f-4337-9215-7e1e036625d1&sheet=828499e7-da76-4f1c-aa43-b4accbfbd203&opt=currsel" data-width="100%" data-height="550px">DASHBOARD II</a></li>
  <li><a id="mySelect" data-src="https://192.168.90.240/single/?appid=1ab7d1b9-5a9f-4337-9215-7e1e036625d1&sheet=89c0893e-d526-4af3-aaf8-68a1d54cb96d&opt=currsel" data-width="100%" data-height="550px">DASHBOARD III</a></li>
  <li><a id="mySelect" data-src="https://192.168.90.240/single/?appid=1ab7d1b9-5a9f-4337-9215-7e1e036625d1&sheet=7b3fe051-8219-469f-994b-7ea249ee2b73&opt=currsel" data-width="100%" data-height="550px">DASHBOARD IV</a></li>
</div>
```

my expected 2 dropdown it's work.

source file :
https://github.com/GoLeR797370/Perpustakaan23.git 
download mashup.html

Answer (score 0):

**First of all:**

Hence, ID's should be unique,, use class if you want to use the same properties on multiple elements!

**Second Problem**

var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');
he only finds the first child:

```
<li><a id="mySelect" data-src="https://192.168.90.240/single/?appid=1ab7d1b9-5a9f-4337-9215-7e1e036625d1&sheet=83e3821d-2afc-45bd-be16-7d95a1065a8d&opt=currsel" data-width="100%" data-height="550px">DASHBOARD I</a></li>
```

or

```
  <li><a id="mySelect" data-src="https://192.168.90.240/single/?appid=1ab7d1b9-5a9f-4337-9215-7e1e036625d1&sheet=83e3821d-2afc-45bd-be16-7d95a1065a8d&opt=currsel" data-width="100%" data-height="550px">DASHBOARD I</a></li>
```

**third problem**

pls show your complete code incl. your frame

Comment: you can get the source code in my github :

https://github.com/GoLeR797370/Perpustakaan23.git

download mashup.html

Comment: pls post your Code in here!

Comment: i cannot share code in here because to long, i post my source code in github you can cek  github.com/GoLeR797370/Perpustakaan23.git download mashup.html